# LDAP validate user uid without knowing his ou

Tags: java, ldap

I have to authenticate users into my system using LDAP, my problem is that i have many organizations and i dont have a list user-organization.

I have this code working forcing a knowing organization:

```
ldap.validate("uid=" + this.email + ",ou="+ThisIsTheOrImForcing+",ou=users,dc=myDC,dc=com,dc=br", this.password);
```

My validation method:

```
public boolean validate(String principal, String password){
    // Set up the environment for creating the initial context
    Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    //env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://IP:PORT/DC=opus");
    //env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://IP:PORT/dc=mydc,dc=com,dc=br");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://IP:PORT/dc=mydc,dc=com,dc=br");

    //Authenticate as S. User and password
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,principal );
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

    try{
        // Create the initial context
        DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
        return true;
    } catch( AuthenticationException ae ) {
        return false;
    } catch( NamingException ne ) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have the var ThisIsTheOrImForcing, how can i authenticate the user without knowing his organization, i have to search for it first, how?

Answer (score 1):

Simple bind in LDAP requires you to provide the DN of the user, hence why you need to know the organization.

You have two ways to deal with it :

- Make a search on your directory for the user which has the attribute `uid = this.email` , retrieve his DN, and authenticate with the found DN to validate the user
- Use other way to authenticate, such as SASL mechanism : [See this for more information](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/ldap/sasl.html). You will also have to look for your Directory configuration which mechanism is supported

Comment: I think the structure of the LDAP implemented here does now alow me to search for DN of a user, but i will have a try.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, `uid` is a unique identifier.  A search operation is used to map the given uid to its distinguished name, so you don't have to worry about the exact place of an account in the directory.